# Finding Points on Plot3D Graph within Sphere

Tags: r

I'm very new to R so I'm using very basic code. I have a Plot3d graph and a sphere within it. I would like to figure out how many points on the graph are located within said sphere. Is this possible? If so, please explain how.

Here is my code so far:

```
Graph <- plot3d(x,z,y, 
   bg = 'black' , 
   xlab = "Horizontal Release" ,
   ylab = "Vertical Release" ,
   zlab = "Length Release" ,
   col.var = Last_Week_Colors_1$V3, 
   col  = c("green", "red"),
   size = 3)
Sphere <- rgl.spheres((Mean_V4), (Mean_V6), (Mean_V5), Radius , alpha = .7, color = 'gray')
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: You don't need any plotting code. Just do `within_sphere <- sqrt((x - Mean_v4)^2 + (y - Mean_V5)^2 + (z - Mean_V6)^2) < Radius`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Continuing, suppose I would like to only count the points that are "green" or "red", how would I do this? I added 

length(within_sphere[within_sphere == TRUE])

What else should I add?

Thanks!

Comment: `... & col == "green"`?